# How to manage build-ids in git? As messages, branches, both or other?

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2017, versioning

A colleague and I were talking about how to manage versioning of source code.  Our company currently has a user-id for creating a null commit with the message stating the build-id.  We use build-ids such as `XXyyyy.zz.bbb` that are auto generated every day, where `XX` is the project id, `yyyy` is the year of the code, `zz` is some number that we don't seem to use as it always seems to be `00`, and `bbb` is the build number which is incremented every day.

If I need to get the source code of a particular build, I need to grep the log to find the hash id and then checkout that hash id to put git into a detached head state.  Or if using the VS IDE, get the history, filter on the user-id, then scroll down to the appropriate item and check it out.

However, I was thinking that perhaps this isn't efficient as maybe using branches, because from the git bash command line, we could use `git checkout builds/XXyyyy/zz/bbb`, or from VS just go into branches and select the tree branch on `builds -> XXyyyy -> zz -> bbb`.  This has the added benefit not putting the repository in a detached head state, and you can easily see where you are from the git-bash command line (though I don't know if this is enough of a reason to do it this way).

Are there any best practices for tracking build-ids in git that I can reference?  Or pros and cons for these two methods?  Perhaps both might be good to use?

FYI, my team is using VS2017 15.6.7.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [git tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) to do this:
`git tag XXyyy.ss.bbb a1b2c3d4`

Then you would check it out later:
`git checkout XXyyy.ss.bbb`

It still puts you in a detached HEAD state, but that should not be worrisome as that "version" should no longer receive any updates since it has been released.

Comment: That's interesting.  However, I don't think that VS2017 has support for tags yet, so unfortunately, I don't think that would be useful. :(

Comment: Also, re comment about no longer receiving updates.  That is not necessarily true as there are the (now more rare) hot fixes that we occasionally produce.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, VS2017 Update 6 does have it. We're just not there yet or maybe I just can't see it. :(  We're using VS2017 15.6.7.